# Wired Internet connection problem

Tags: internet, connection, lan, router, wired

I have a local Internet connection which I use with a router.
But, I want to connect the Internet cable directly to my PC and use Internet on my PC without using a router.

After I connect the cable to my PC, Ubuntu shows it as a wired connection without Internet.
My service provider gave me a userid and password, but don't know where to enter it in Ubuntu.

Comment: What kind of connection it is? PPPoE or what? What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: This is a Bad Idea. Every usec you're connected to The Internet, The Internet is connected to you. Why avoid the router?

Comment: it is a PPPoE connection